# How can I check if a given date is newer than 3 days?

Tags: php, laravel, date

I have a date

2016-09-16

How can I check that if that date is less than 3 days old?

I'm being really stupid and the frustration is making me not figure it out

Here's my code

```
public function isNew()
{
    return strtotime($this->created_at) > time() && strtotime($this->created_at) < strtotime('+3 days',time());
}
```

Comment: The question is ambiguous. The title says "*newer than 3 days*", but the question body says "*less than 3 days old*". A date that's less than 3 days old need not be *between* now and 3 days from now, does it? The difference between that date and the present date just needs to be less than 3 days. So `abs(time() - strtotime($this->created_at)) < (3 * 24 * 60 * 60)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be easy to use DateTime and DateInterval to handle this.

```
$date = new DateTime('2016-09-16');

$diff = (new DateTime)->diff($date)->days;

return $diff < 3;
```

Comment: Sorry, typo.  It's really `DateTime`

Answer (score 1):

Use `diff()`. It will return a `DateInterval` object.  Within that object will be a days property (`days`) that you can access.

```
// compare two distinct dates:

$datetime1 = new DateTime('2016-09-16');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('2016-09-12');
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
$daysOld = $interval->days;
// int(4) 

// or compare today vs your date...

$datetime1 = new DateTime('2016-09-16');
$now = new DateTime();
$interval = $now->diff($datetime1);
$daysOld = $interval->days;
// int(0) 


// then determine if it's at least 3 days old:
$is3daysOld = ($daysOld >= 3 ? true : false);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php

Comment: `$interval->d` is wrong here, because that represents the difference in days, substrate years and months, and not as an absolute value. For example `(new DateTime('2016-09-16'))->diff(new DateTime('2015-09-16'))->d === 0`, however, `(new DateTime('2016-09-16'))->diff(new DateTime('2015-09-16'))->days === 366`.

Comment: Thanks @Sherif. Great catch.  Edited answer for historical purposes with the correction.

Answer (score 1):

Using PHP's `DateTime` and `DateInterval` Classes would do you much good. Here's how:

```
<?php

    function isNewerThan3Days($date) {
        $today  = new DateTime();
        $date   = new DateTime($date);

        $diff   = $today->diff($date);
        $diffD  = $diff->days;
        if($diffD>=3){              
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    var_dump(isNewerThan3Days("2016-09-14"));   //<== YIELDS:: boolean true
```

Comment: `$diff->d` is wrong here, because that represents the difference in days, substrate years and months, and not as an absolute value. For example `(new DateTime('2016-09-16'))->diff(new DateTime('2015-09-16'))->d === 0`, however, `(new DateTime('2016-09-16'))->diff(new DateTime('2015-09-16'))->days === 366`.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it for you.

```
$date = new DateTime('2015-09-16');
$now = new DateTime();

$interval = $date->diff($now);
$difference = $interval->format('%a');

if($difference < 3) {
    // $date is fewer than 3 days ago
}
```

In your `isNew()` method:

```
public function isNew() {
    $created_at = new DateTime($this->created_at);
    $now = new DateTime();

    $interval = $created_at->diff($now);
    $difference = $interval->format('%a');

    if($difference < 3) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Not sure, maybe it's because mine is way easier to understand?

Comment: @RobertWade Actually, that was me and it was not every answer. I commented on your answer why I down voted. It is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

```
return $this->created_at->diffInDays() < 3;
```

Without parameter `diffInDays()` will return the number of complete days between `created_at` and now.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use [Carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) ? 
You can easily do that and many more in carbon like so :

```
$dt = Carbon::createFromDate(2011, 8, 1);
echo $dt->subDays(5)->diffForHumans();               // 5 days before
```